# Google Analytics Referrer Source not recognized

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, referrals

I am a beginner in Google Analytics, so need help about this. I configured my website point per point like it said in Google, but something is not working. The links I insert in my page won't get in their analytics that they came from my page. It shows as Direct/None . Is there any mistake done by me or not. Is it possible to be recognized the source without putting the UTM Codes behind the link.

Ex.:
http://www.yourpage.com/?utm_source=mypage.com&utm_medium=MyPage.com+Link

This works it shows that the visit came from mypage.com, but if I set the link like this:

http://www.yourpage.com/

It wont be recognized, it shows only like Direct/None.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you link to a third party from your page and it's their analytics that does not show the referral information.

No, there is nothing you can do, that's a problem on the end of the third party. Maybe they have accidentally added your url to their referral exclusion list, in that case traffic via your site would always show up as direct traffic.

But it's nothing that you are doing. Referrer traffic should be recognised automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but I have another page. I made test traffic to that page and went to analytics it shows too as Direct so I think the only way is using UTM Campaign tracking codes. Best solution for now. Am I right?